# How to remove multiple zip files in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, quote

I am trying to remove a set of multiple zipped directories in BASH. These directories have spaces between them, so when I try to delete them, they interfere with the spaces.

I have tried removing the directories by using a for loop.

```
 direc=`ls -d *.zip` 
 for eachDir in $direc 
 do
     echo $eachDir
     rm -r $eachDir
 done
```

Each word in my directory name is being treated as a seperate directory (because of the spaces) which causes an error in deleting the zipped file.

I have also tried using:

```
FILES=$(find . -name "*.zip")
for val in $FILES
do
        echo $val
done
```

From both these pieces of code, my result is the same[image: Zipped Files]

*As seen from the photos, "Whos"  "Wants" and "To"... are all seen as seperate files as space is causing this. How can I fix this?*

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: If you want to delete a file, why do you use the `-r` option?

Comment: What's wrong with ```rm -r *.zip```?

Comment: @Cyrus my bad, im deleting directories

Comment: @Michael You have directories with names ending in .zip?

Comment: @GordonDavisson yup, a lot of them

Comment: @Michael: I suggest to fix your headline and question.

Answer (score 3):

`find` will traverse all sub-directories and delete any *.zip files

```
find . -name \*.zip -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the following snippet, using the *internal field separator* and `find` command:

```sh
while IFS=  read -r -d $'\n'; do
   echo "Remove $(basename "$REPLY")"
   rm $(basename "$REPLY")
done < <(find ./*.zip)
```

---

Edit: With `find` you can traverse through directories as well. For example, have a look at [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187167/traverse-all-subdirectories-in-and-do-something-in-unix-shell-script)

Comment: If the directories are not empty, the script tries to delete the files from the subdirectories in the current directory.

Comment: Probably you are right, but this is only a snippet how it could be achieved. Of course, there is no checking. And with ```find```you can select *min-* and *maxdepth*.